# Using Jquery unload function to delete user from online users list

Tags: php, jquery

I want to know is there a way correct way to delete user from online users list with `$(window).unload` jQuery function?
or keep using PHP to check it?
i think this is not a correct way because user can edit it, but i need more reasons.
Code example:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(window).unload(function() {

   $.ajax({ 
   type: "GET", 
   url: 'http://localhost/delete_session.php', 
   data: "id=" + "session id";
   });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's a common approach to handle **online users** : You can create a table that hold their ids with timestamps. On each request you'd update a timestamp. And you can handle it like, `If (time() -$last_timestamp > 120){ offlie } else { still online }`

Comment: @djay Thank you, I am using the same method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't work well with multiple tabs : if your the user opens your app in two different tabs, closing any of the two tabs will delete the session, and the other tab will become "unusable".

You should not solely rely on the client's behaviour to manage your sessions : the client's browser may exit incorrectly (program bug, battery out, `kill -9`, etc...) and not execute the unload callback on exit.

Answer (score 0):

A correct way to do online list is probably using heartbeat requests.

Your javascript sends small requests to server indicating they are "alive".

If all pages are closed by user, the heartbeat stops and you somehow remove it from online user list on the server.